# In the View how to send a data in javascript to the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable and I want, when I click some row I get row id and go back to the controller and uptade some data by the row id. I am getting row id(data.SiparisID) BUT I cant send data to controller`@section scripts{

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


    });
    $("#SiparisTable").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Goster/getList",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
             { "data": "SiparisID" },
            { "data": "SiparisAd" },
            { "data": "SiparisModel" },
            { "data": "SiparisTur" },
            { "data": "SiparisAdet" },
            { "data": "SiparisTarih" },
            { "data": "SiparisDurum" },
            {
                "data": "SiparisID", "render": function () {
                    return "<input type='submit' value='Güncelle' class='btn btn-default' onclick='backoperation()' />"

                }


            }

        ]

    });



    var table = $('#SiparisTable').DataTable();
    $('#SiparisTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        alert('You clicked on ' + data.SiparisID + '\'s row');
    });



</script>
<script>


    function backoperation() {

        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Guncelle")";
    }
</script>
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

```
 function backoperation() {

    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Guncelle")?param=obj";
}
```

this case it redirect to another page
or

you can make request through Ajax request

```
"ajax": {
        "url": "/Goster/getList??param=obj",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
```

then it come in your controller
 this case it updated in same view

Comment: Thank for the answer your code learnd something me and ı found the answer for me have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
   var table = $('#SiparisTable').DataTable();
    $('#SiparisTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        alert('You clicked on ' + data.SiparisID + '\'s row');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Guncelle/Process',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                id: data.SiparisID,

                success: function () { },
                error: function () { }
            }
        });
    });**THE VIEW**
```

public ActionResult Process(int id)**THE CONTROLLER**
        {}
I found this and this work for me. I can get the id in the script with this controller